# Can RTMP link be found from this code to play in my JW player

Tags: jwplayer, wireshark, rtmp, m3u8

Below is the code i got from wireshark can you tell me how to make that rtmp link work in JW player.

`8<...q.v..j......[...{v.%.......z........connect.?..........app...edge/..flashVer...MAC 21,0,0,216..swfUrl..>http://offsidestreams.com/js/jwplayer-7.3.6/jwplayer.flas.h.swf..tcUrl.. rtmp://62.210.102.219:1935/edge/..fpad....capabilities.@m........audioCodecs.@.........videoCodecs.@o.......
vide.oFunction.?.........pageUrl..@http://offsidestreams.com/live-streams/sky-sports-f1-hd.564.html..objectEncoding...........  .............&%..............&%..................................................._result.?..........fmsVer...FMS/3,5,7,7009..capabilities.@?........mode.?.........    ...level...status..code...NetConnection.Connect.Success..description...Connection succeeded...data.......version..
3,5,7,7009..    ..clientid.A.N.!.....objectEncoding...........  ..@..........&%....N...........createStream.@........B.....
.........................._result.@.........?..........O...........play............z2587?token=9b305a0d45ef22fd34d6f5afee8cbe6f&bid=1&pid=2&uid=71356&did=d5e89cbe306f1381072e40a9b25f9495&g=1&g............m=1&platform=1.................................onStatus.............level...status..code...NetStream.Play.Reset..description...Playing and resetting 2587...clientid.A.N.!..... ...............onStatus.............level...status..code...NetStream.Play.Start..description...Started playing 2587...clientid.A.N.!....
isFastPlay....timecodeOffset..  70618282L.. E..........|RtmpSampleAccess..........,........onStatus...code...NetStream.Data.Start.. ............. ....E.........
onMetaData...duration...........width.@.........height.@........
videodatarate.......... framerate.@9........videocodecid.@........
audiodatarate.@_@.......audiosamplerate.@.........audiosamplesize.@0........stereo....audiocodecid.@$........Server...NGINX RTMP (github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module)..displayWidth...1280.
displayHeight...720..fps...25..profile.....level.....encoder..
Lavf57.21.101..filesize...........  ......*`

Comment: Have you tried looking at the Wireshark dissection of the traffic, rather than the "Follow TCP Stream" output?

Comment: @GuyHarris can u explain or provide a link on how to do Wireshark dissection of the traffic

Comment: Load the file into Wireshark, find all the frames for the connection (doing "Follow TCP Stream" on any packet in the connection will do that), and then, for each of the frames, select it and, in the packet detail pane, open up all the items for the protocols running on top of TCP.